How to connect to external MSSQL server in Mendix which has windows authentication enabled?
Our team is trying to connect to an MSSQL server with Windows authentication that is hosted in our environment. However, we've encountered an error message stating "Invalid JDBC connection string." We're unsure of what specifically is causing this issue. I'd like to confirm the following:
Is it possible to connect to databases with Windows authentication enabled in Mendix?
If the answer is yes, I would greatly appreciate your assistance in providing the correct format for converting a MSSQL connection string into a JDBC connection string.

Could you please edit the question to provide some examples of your connection-strings that work for SQL Server and the connection-strings that are rejected as invalid for JDBC?

In general you can enable the integrated security to use the Windows authentication like so:
jdbc:sqlserver://172.31.255.255;encrypt=true;database=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;

Is your app running in the Mendix cloud?
You somehow need to pass your Windows credentials for using integrated security.
